# azimuth CMS - Loading page hanging forever

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I just installed Azimuth-views-foundation everything went well. Then I did mrt in my app, mrt told me the app is running at localhost:3000. But when I open localhost:3000 I got a never ending loading page.

I waited for more than 15mn and it is still running.

Anyone else has the same issue?

when I debug this is what I have

Error: http://louxew-98410.use1-2.nitrousbox.com/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18 is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

that's the same error for all packages that have been downloaded along with azimuth-views-foundation

I am running meteor 0.8.0

Comment: I'm running meteor 0.8.1.1 and have same problem (OSX platform)

Comment: This issue is fixed now, go on the github issues page you will see the corresponence I had with the CMS Author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed now, go on the github issues page you will see the corresponence I had with the CMS Author.